# Does usage of black backgrounds on webpages really helps in saving energy?

Tags: css, background, energy

Does the use of a black background like [Blackle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackle) proclaims, really save energy for Google searches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only on CRTs. LCDs have a backlight which is always on, even if black is being shown.

Blackle themselves show this table:

[image: Variation in Monitor On Power for selected Monitors (conclusion is LCD is not important, CRT makes a difference if up to 188% more power usage for white rather than black. Minimum difference is 118% more.]

Comment: that means this concept is going to be true only upto heart beat counts for CRT monitors?

Comment: I've added the table from Blackle.

Comment: But toggling each red, green, and blue filter (sub)cell (on LCD monitors) *should* still draw power right?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess so, but I suspect that in comparison to having the backlight on, it's not as important.

Comment: @RichBradshaw  Thx for all the info :)